# How can I make python distinguish between different users in my "money.py" file?

Tags: python

Here is my code:-

```
f= open("Passes.py", "a+")
m=open("money.py","a+")
passes= {}
init={}
initial=0
import time
wait=time.sleep(0.5)
print "Welcome to the virtual banking system"
wait
user=raw_input("Would you like to create a new account? 'Y/N'").lower()
if user== "y":
  new_user= raw_input("Create a username:")
  new_pass= raw_input("Create a password:")
  p= passes[new_user]= new_user + ":" + new_pass
  f.write("\n"+p)
  ask=raw_input("Would you like to sign into your account? 'Y/N'").lower()
  if ask=="y":
    user_in=raw_input("Enter your username:")
    if user_in==new_user:
      pass_in=raw_input("Enter your password:")
      if pass_in==new_pass:
        running=True
        while running:
          print "Welcome to your account" + " " + new_user
          useropt=raw_input("Would you like to view your balance- enter 1, deposit money- enter 2 or withdraw money- enter 3:")
          if useropt=="1":
            print "Your balance is:", initial
            m.write("\n"+str(initial))
          if useropt=="2":
            m.close()
            u=open("money.py","r+")
            amountdep= int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit?:"))
            initial+=amountdep
            print "Thanks. Your new balance is:", initial
            u.write(str(initial)+"\n")
          if useropt=="3":
            m.close()
            r=open("money.py","r+")
            amountwith=int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?:"))
            initial-=amountwith
            if initial>=0:
              print "Your balance is:", initial
              r.write(str(initial)+"\n")
            else:
              print "Sorry, this amount cannot be withdrawn. Balance cannot be less than 0"
          cont = raw_input("Would you like to do another operation? 'Y/N'").lower()
          running = cont == "y"
      else:
        print "Password not valid"

    else:
      print "Username does not exist"

  else:
    print "Thanks for using the virtual bank."

else:
  user2=raw_input("Do you have an existing account? 'Y/N'").lower()
  if user2=="y":
    existing_user=raw_input("Enter your username:")
    exisitng_pass=raw_input("Enter your password:")
    for passwords in f:
      if passwords==existing_user+":"+exisitng_pass:
        run=True
        while run:
          print "Welcome to your account" + " " + existing_user
          with open("money.py", "r") as m:
            info= int(m.readline().strip())
            useropt2=raw_input("Would you like to view your balance- enter 1, deposit money- enter 2 or withdraw money- enter 3:")
            if useropt2=="1":
              print "Your balance is:", info
            if useropt2=="2":
              amountdep= int(raw_input("How much money would you like to deposit?:"))
              a=info+int(amountdep)
              print "Your new balance is:", a
              with open("money.py", "w") as m:
                  m.write(str(a))
            if useropt2=="3":
              amountwith=int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?:"))
              t=info-int(amountwith)
              if t>=0:
                print "Your balance is:", t
                with open("money.py", "w") as m:
                  m.write(str(t))
              else:
                print "Sorry, this amount cannot be withdrawn. Balance cannot be less than 0"
            restart = raw_input("Would you like to do another operation? 'Y/N'").lower()
            run = restart == "y"
      else:
        print "Invalid username or password"
  else:
    print "Thanks for using the virtual bank."
```

I have two files, and one of them is "money.py." In this file, the total amount of money in my user's account is stored. The problem, though is there is currently no way to distinguish between two users and their money in my program, as it just stores the integer value of their total amount. I also tried, writing the username and then the amount of money, but found that this does not work, as it mixes strings and integers. Is there a way to distinguish between different users? Thanks.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This question would've been better put to stackoverflow.

My suggestion is to store your balances in a dictionary e.g. `balances[user] = amount` and use the `json` module to read / write it from the file

to load:

```
with open("money.py", "r") as moneyfile:
    balances = json.load(moneyfile)
```

to save:

```
with open("money.py", "w") as moneyfile:
    json.dump(balances, moneyfile)
```

note: `.py` is the extension used for python source code, for storing data another extension is preferred, e.g. `.txt` or `.dat`